# How can I get all the initialized managed beans in the session?

Tags: java, jsf-2, myfaces

How can I get all the initialized managed beans in the session?
Following code crashes the JVM every time.

```
FacesContext facesContext=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate application = 
ApplicationAssociate.getInstance(facesContext.getExternalContext());
```

Comment: Can't you use the jconsole? That is what I use when searching for running beans

Comment: I actually need to get them through the code.

Comment: you want to get one session scope bean in another one ? use managedproperty...

Comment: No @Daniel I do not need to inject them not talking about `managedproperty` I need to know with one bean all the beans that are with in that same session . Basically there is a method in these beans so those beans that are in the session I need to access them and call that method and let go .

Comment: ow, haven't read the title properly... another approach is to insert the session bean into a list that will be maintained by the application scope bean , and iterate over them... but then you need to maintain it...

Comment: @Daniel yes thats a good idea too . Have upvoted your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use something like

```
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
 Enumeration mySessionBeans = session.getAttributeNames();
```

Comment: Thats sounds more like it. Will try:)